# Multiple conditions for printing arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `A` with shape `(3,3,3)`. I want to print `A[0], A[1], A[2]` only when at least one of the elements of `A[0], A[1], A[2]` is `<=10 or>=30`. But I am getting an error. The expected output is attached.

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[[41,42,43],[44,45,46],[47,48,49]],[[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19]],
            [[31,32,33],[34,35,36],[37,38,39]]])

for t in range(0,len(A)):
    if(A[t]<=10 or A[t]>=30):
        print(A[t])
    else:
        print("STOP")
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    if(A[t]<=10 or A[t]>=30):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The expected output is

```
array([[41, 42, 43],
       [44, 45, 46],
       [47, 48, 49]]) #since no single element of A[0] satisfy <=10 or>=30.

STOP #since A[1] satisfies <=10 or>=30.
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output for clarity?

Comment: Did you look at `A[t]<=10` individually?  Does it make sense to use it in an `if` or `or`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `all()` as you want to satisfy each value with the condition.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[[41, 42, 43],
               [44, 45, 46],
               [47, 48, 49]],
              [[11, 12, 13],
               [14, 15, 16],
               [17, 18, 19]],
              [[31, 32, 33],
               [34, 35, 36],
               [37, 38, 39]]])

for i in range(len(A)):
    if (A[i] <= 10).all() or (A[i] >= 30).all():
        print(A[i])
    else:
        print("STOP")
```

## Output

```
[[41 42 43]
 [44 45 46]
 [47 48 49]]
STOP
[[31 32 33]
 [34 35 36]
 [37 38 39]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The iterator will be returning an entire 'row' (or whatever that is in three dimensions), not a single element.  If you put:

```
print(A[t])
```

in before the test, you'll see what you're checking against:

```
[[41 42 43]
 [44 45 46]
 [47 48 49]]
```

so you'll need to 'dig in' to the array a little more by having nested loops.